# Hystrix: cannot trip circuit breaker

Tags: hystrix

Assuming i use the default Hystrix configurations:

```
CircuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold=20    
CircuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage=50    
MetricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds=10000ms
```

I assume this means that within a 10 sec window, the circuit will break if there are 10 handled exceptions within 20 consecutive requests.
I have a class called MyCommand which extends HystrixCommand. I create 20 objects of it and call execute on each sequentially. But I don't seem to trip the circuit because it never goes into my getFallback method. I expected the 20th execute to trip the circuit. Where am i going wrong?

```
int i=0;    
    public MyObject run() throws Exception {    
        i++;    
        try {    
            throw new Exception("Handled exception "+i);    
        } catch (Exception e) {    
            System.out.print("Catch "+i);    
        }    
        return null;    
    }
```

Comment: Here is a related comment: within a timespan of duration metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds, the percentage of actions resulting in a handled exception exceeds errorThresholdPercentage, provided also that the number of actions through the circuit in the timespan is at least requestVolumeThreshold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you handle the exceptions within the command then the circuit breaker will not open.   In your run method do not catch the exception.

Comment: But what about the case where you're ok with 50% errors but not more. I'm trying to understand the above 3 properties.